# Python and selenium : firefox keep creating dialog boxes when downloading even if i set its preferences

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I wrote a program using selenium and firefox web driver.

```
def dowloadFile(link):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 
    'application/pdf')

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    #driver.set_window_position(-10000,0)
    driver.get(link)
    s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    st=s.find('div',{"class":"bloc-docs-link bloc-250"})
    #print("hadiii ST: "+str(st))
    x=st.find('a')
    fm=x.get('href')
    fm="https://www.marchespublics.gov.ma/"+fm
    driver.get(fm)
    driver.quit()
```

my function takes as parameter a link, after that it gets that link and finally find another one which downloads the file.
my problem is, even if I set preferences of my firefox, it always keep showing dialog boxes when downloading, to confirm if i want to save it! I dont know what to do so I can download the file without this dialog box.

Any help please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with that too. I've just done this instead. Note: it does take more time so if you have a ton of files you're downloading, this may not be worth it. Otherwise, this will do the trick.

Create an alert object that's ready to be used on the dialogue boxes, like this for example:

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
```

Import Expected Conditions:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Then, create a function that directs the browser to wait until the expected condition (the alert) is prompted.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present()
except TimeoutException:
```

It's best to put this is a try/except block, but not mandatory.

Then, simply use the 'accept' method of the alert object to confirm the download after selenium has taken control of the alert window:

```
alert.accept()
```

The function could look something like this:

```
    try:
        alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert_wait()
        alert.accept()
    except print('No alertfound')
```

Also, I would highly recommend using the requests/BeautifulSoup module for this so you don't have to render the browser and experience the delays that come with navigating through a ton of web pages. The requests module does it all behind the scenes. This gets tricky if you need to enter a password prior to downloading. If not, the BeautifulSoup library is awesome for scraping tags/hrefs, collecting them in a list, and then looping over them one by one using the similar requests.get() method.

In fact, the last time I had this problem, I used the requests module instead of selenium and the alert windows were automatically accepted. Lightening fast, too.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer; my case is that i have tones of files for dowloading. so the program will for sure be slow. from what i understood the: profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDi‌​sk', 'application/pdf') is the responsible of not letting the browser show the dialog box. dont know why it doesn't work.

Comment: from what I remember, selenium is full of bugs like that. Also, Firefox had been cracking down on people like us, 'web scrapers' so they're done their part in making it quite difficult. 

I never use firefox. I personally find Chrome browser to be the best from what I've tried.

Comment: Oh, one last thing (couldn't edit the first comment because it had been after 5 mins? Al these rules, eh?). I digress,
 
This may be getting way into the weeds, but I would give using asyncio/coroutines/threading a try as part of your script. They're a big part of what's making Python famous. 

Before I leave you alone here, I would absolutely recommend checking out "Fluent Python" by Luciano Ramalho. Free on Github. You will be SO happy you did. Luciano, the author, covers coroutines very well so you could even skip to that for starters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using beautifulsoup?! Make use of `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`

Secondly, please confirm that the PDF file you're targetting actually has the appropriate mimetype. See http://yizeng.me/2014/05/23/download-pdf-files-automatically-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver/